# Oracle Loop Rule 4809

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a procedure that will insert thousands of rows in a table and use the auto generated id resulted from these rows and use it in other inserts.

I used a for loop in which I save the sequence id in a variable then use it in my inserts.

```
declare
first_id integer;
BEGIN
FOR texts in (select distinct text from table_texts  )
 LOOP
first_id := SEQ_IDS_OBJECTID.NEXTVAL;
INSERT INTO  table_1(id,some_fields)
VALUES (first_id, 'blablabla');

insert into table_2 (id,text_field)
 VALUES (first_id, texts.text);
END LOOP;
commit;
 END;
```

I think that this is not the ideal way to achieve what I need. Also when I enter the code in TOAD , I get the following warning :
Rule 4809 (A loop that contains DML statements should be refactored to use BULK COLLECT and FORALL)

Is there better way to do it?

EDIT:

the above code was simplified. But I think I have to expose more of it to explain the case :

```
declare
first_id  integer;
second_id integer;

BEGIN


FOR texts in (select distinct text1 , text2  from mdf )

LOOP

first_id := XAKTA.SEQ_IDS_OBJECTID.NEXTVAL;

select id_1 into second_id from table_3 where  field_1 =texts.text1 ;

INSERT INTO  table_1(id_1,id_2,some_fields)
VALUES (first_id ,second_id ,'blablabla');

insert into table_2 (id,text1,text2)
 VALUES (first_id, texts.text1,texts.text2);

END LOOP;    
commit;
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FORALL` to insert batches of items from your cursor:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE texts_tab IS TABLE OF table_texts.text%TYPE;
  TYPE ids_tab   IS TABLE OF table_2.id%TYPE;
  p_texts texts_tab;
  p_ids   ids_tab;
  CURSOR c IS
    SELECT DISTINCT text FROM table_texts;
BEGIN
  OPEN c;
  LOOP
    FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO p_texts LIMIT 100;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. p_texts.COUNT
      INSERT INTO table_2 ( id, text_field )
                   VALUES ( SEQ_IDS_OBJECTID.NEXTVAL, p_texts(i) )
      RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO p_ids;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. p_ids.COUNT
      INSERT INTO  table_1( id, some_fields )
        VALUES ( p_ids(i), 'blablabla' );

    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c01291ff2ad1466589ac7707284a62ec)*

Comment: Thank you! What if table_texts table contains two fields : SELECT DISTINCT text1,text2 FROM table_texts; where both text1 and text2 will be used.  what will change in this case ?

Comment: I edited the post with a more realistic code. Can you please check it ?